# supervisord not restarting on HUP signal

Tags: supervisord

```
sudo kill -SIGHUP `cat /var/run/supervisor.pid`
```

causes supervisor to kill it's child processes then itself but it doesn't restart as per the docs. Same behaviour if I call `reload` from within supervisorctl.

Version: 3.0b1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably your bug: https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/issues/121

It should be fixed in 3.0b2, for now the author recommends downgrading to 3.0a12